# how do i can restart NPM for Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm, localhost

I'm rookie how to setup reactjs with NPM, after setting is working great when I see output said "hello world", by going to URL localhost:8080.

But this time I created more new folder move index.html and index.js to new folder, and I changed to "It works great" from "hello world" under new folder, but currently showing old output "hello world"

My question is that how can I re-run NPM after made changed webconfig.js and package.json! and the output should be showing under new folder file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently are you using any webserver for serving the app? You can use webPack or gulp. Webpack is my preference. You can see hot loader option while configuring it. Hot loader provides option to listen for changes mentioned in any file.

Comment: i use this hot loader in pack.json.  scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/indx.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },

Comment: you can check package.jason at [link](https://jsfiddle.net/7htzdso5/2/)

Comment: please check my package.jason at jsfiddle.net [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7htzdso5/2/)

Comment: Both are webconfig.js file. I need to see package.json file which contains all the dependency information and scripts to run the server.